# Spring security concurrency-control does not work

Tags: java, spring-security

I try to implement concurrency-control in Spring security 3.2.
I use form-login for auth.
Here is my security.xml

```
    <beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

<http access-denied-page="/login.html" create-session="ifRequired">

    <intercept-url pattern="/settings.html" access="ROLE_USER"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/history.html" access="ROLE_USER"/>

    <form-login login-page="/"
                authentication-failure-url="/error.do"
                default-target-url="/logged.do"
                always-use-default-target="true"
                login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"/>

    <logout logout-url="/j_spring_security_logout" logout-success-url="/index.html" invalidate-session="true"/>   

    <session-management session-authentication-strategy-ref="sas"/>

    <custom-filter ref="accessFilter" after="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" />
    <custom-filter position="CONCURRENT_SESSION_FILTER" ref="concurrencyFilter" />
    <custom-filter before="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="myAuthFilter" />
</http>

<beans:bean id="sessionRegistry" class="org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl" />

<beans:bean id="accessFilter" class="ua.com.site.http.filter.PlayerAccessFilter" />

<beans:bean id="passwordUserDetailService" class="ua.com.site.web.security.cristal.PasswordUserDetailService">
    <beans:property name="playerDao" ref="playerDao"/>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="tokenUserDetailsService" class="ua.com.site.web.security.cristal.TokenUserDetailService">
    <beans:property name="playerDao" ref="playerDao"/>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="passwordAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
    <beans:property name="passwordEncoder">
        <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.Md5PasswordEncoder" />
    </beans:property>
    <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="passwordUserDetailService" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="tokenAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
    <beans:property name="passwordEncoder">
        <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.PlaintextPasswordEncoder" />
    </beans:property>
    <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="tokenUserDetailsService" />
</beans:bean>

<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider ref="passwordAuthenticationProvider" />
    <authentication-provider ref="tokenAuthenticationProvider" />
</authentication-manager>

<beans:bean id="concurrentSessionController" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy">
    <beans:constructor-arg name="sessionRegistry" ref="sessionRegistry" />
    <beans:property name="maximumSessions" value="1" />
</beans:bean>


<beans:bean id="concurrencyFilter"
   class="org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter">
  <beans:property name="sessionRegistry" ref="sessionRegistry" />
  <beans:property name="expiredUrl" value="/expired.html" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="myAuthFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter">
  <beans:property name="sessionAuthenticationStrategy" ref="sas" />
  <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="sas" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy">
  <beans:constructor-arg>
    <beans:list>
      <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy">
        <beans:constructor-arg ref="sessionRegistry"/>
        <beans:property name="maximumSessions" value="1" />
        <beans:property name="exceptionIfMaximumExceeded" value="true" />
      </beans:bean>
      <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.SessionFixationProtectionStrategy">
      </beans:bean>
      <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy">
        <beans:constructor-arg ref="sessionRegistry"/>
      </beans:bean>
    </beans:list>
  </beans:constructor-arg>
</beans:bean>
```

Listener

```
<listener-class>
org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher
</listener-class>
```

is included to my web.xml.

I strat the app, run it in different browsers, log in in both but I have 2 sessions active. It seems that concurrency control doesn't work.

How to implement concurrency control with using form-login?

In previous versions I just used

```
<session-management>
        <concurrency-control max-sessions="1" expired-url="/expired.html" error-if-maximum-exceeded="false" session-registry-ref="sessionRegistry" />
    </session-management>
```

Thank you for any advice.

Comment: And why are you now configuring everything yourself?

Comment: Not myself. I try to use samples from documentation. But using <custom-filter after="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="myAuthFilter" /> with form-login causes an exception

Comment: I don't get why you changed your working configuration for an upgrade of Spring Security?

Comment: It was manager's decision to upgrade verion. My task is only to fix  this issue(

Comment: Again why do the cumbersome configuration if it works with a single line of XML...

Comment: It worked in previous versions of spring security. but in v3.2 it doesn't. So I try to refactor it.

Comment: Why as your current config is making it worse. Your session-management conflicts with the concurrent-session filter, one overrides the other.  Why did you change it even instead. Your configuration isn't making it easier to solve nor to configure.

Comment: I'm not good at spring security. I changed filters' order so now I don't have an exception. But I still can log in from different browsers on the same account. Session doesn't expire. What's wrong with my configuration?

Comment: As I iterated before you are making things too complex, just replace the configuration as it was. You don't need to configure everything yourself. You are just making things worse instead of better.

Answer (score 1):

SessionRegistry uses equals()/hashCode() of UserDetails to find sessions of the same user. I have custom UserDetails, so I had to implement this methods and revert previous configuration.